# Request Method POST not shown in nginx $request_method parameter

Tags: nginx, httprequest

I have a question regarding the parameter $request_method of nginx. Whenever I enter the URI (`localhost/ws/v1`) in the browser, the `$request_method`  always return the GET method. why is the POST method not reflected in the variable?

Input using Fiddler

```
POST http://107.105.147.73/ws/v1


nginx.conf
-----------------------------------
 location /ws/v1/{

                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

                echo $request_method;

fastcgi_params
-----------------------------------

#fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

If you're entering in the browser that's a GET by default.  Try

```
curl -X POST http://107.105.147.73/ws/v1
```

You might have to add parameters but you get the gist of it.